# Unable to create custom toolbars in VSTO 2003(Template project) in design time

Tags: vsto

I am trying to create a Word 2003 Template project in Visual Studio 2008.

Customize button is disabled in the TemplateProject toolbar.

Could anyone please let me know if there are any options in VSTO  to create custom toolbars and menus in design time?

I am able to create them programmatically. By using the following code:

newToolbar = ThisApplication.ActiveDocument.CommandBars.Add("CMS Pitch", 
Office.MsoBarPosition.msoBarFloating, false, false);
           newToolbar.Left = 10;
           newToolbar.Top =200;
           newToolbar.Visible = true;

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, in Office 2003 projects, you won't be able to create these visually.